# Can SSH as root, but can not restart. "cannot execute binary file"

Tags: linux

I have a server that's been humming along just fine. I have not made any changes to it in some time. Today, when I tried to login, it immediately logged me back out, even as root. The exchange goes like this:

```
$ ssh root@remote.example.com
root@remote.example.com's password: 
Linux rp0 3.6.11+ #456 PREEMPT Mon May 20 17:42:15 BST 2013 armv6l

Last login: Thu Dec 22 18:38:12 1955 from x�����
Connection to remote.example.com closed.
$
```

(I have no idea what those misinterpreted characters are.)

If I run the following, I can stay connected:

```
$ ssh root@remote.example.com bash
```

But I can't run any binaries from there:

```
shutdown -r now
bash: line 6: /sbin/shutdown: cannot execute binary file
```

Bash commands such as `ls` and `cd` seem to work fine. Oddly enough, a few binaries, such as `cat` and `id` do seem to work.

I suspect that, as soon as this machine reboots, things will be back to working order, for at least a little while. Anyone know how I can, remotely, do just that?

Comment: Have you tried `sh` instead of `bash`?

Comment: `/sbin/shutdown -r now`
`/sbin/shutdown: 1: /sbin/shutdown: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")`

Comment: Can you check what is your shell for the users (including root) in `/etc/passwd`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

This uses the Magic SysReq method of rebooting, minus the keystrokes. echo is a builtin, so your bacon is saved :)

Comment: Interestingly, I did this, and the machine did attempt to reboot (or at least, shutdown) but it has not come back up. I guess it was in worse shape than I realized. Oh well!

Comment: It was pretty broken when you started, so you didn't lose much? Sort of? Oh well, recovery terminal time :)